# Include wide image in HTML email and still have text wrap on iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, email, layout

Usually when you send out emails on an iPhone, the text wraps to the window so the font is a normal size. However, if you set a width, or include an element which is wider than the viewport (like a table or a wide image), the text will fail to wrap, and will display at a lower font size. I've tested this myself by sending [sample emails](http://goodmorningcmc.com/static/cmc/january/19/index.html) with and without a 650px-wide image.

Is there a way to include the 650px wide image, but still have the text wrap on an iPhone? I would still want the email to display properly in a regular browser. Thanks for the help,
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kevin, I think your best bet is to use media queries here to resize that image on smaller screens. I ran into this issue with my clients who wanted mobile emails but were still putting large images into their mailings.

Check out the campaign monitor post for more info:
http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3163/optimizing-your-emails-for-mobile-devices-with-media/